# Function that returns more than one thing

Tags: c

I'm currently learning C, and I'm trying to make a function that returns more that one thing. I've written the code but one of the values is not giving me the right output and I cant figure out why it does that.

```
struct num {
    int min;
    int max;
};

struct num Some(int Array[]) {
    int i;
    struct num result;
    result.max = Array[0];
    result.min = Array[0];
    for(i = 0; i<=3; i++) {
        if(result.min > Array[i]) {
            result.min = Array[i];
        } else if(result.max < Array[i]) {
            result.max = Array[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int Array[] = {7,8,3};
    struct num something;
    something  = Some(Array);
    printf("Total is %d and max is %d",something.min,something.max);
}
```

The program prints the correct minimum value of the array but the max value it gives 4200784.

Comment: In general, a function should only return something simple: a float, an int or a pointer.  In this case you should pass in a pointer to the struct minmax as an argument and not have a return value.

Comment: Yes i did it with pointers but i was testing other ways of returning multiple values from a function

Comment: Returning a small structure like this is a great way to make a function that returns multiple values, and you're doing it exactly right, except for the `<=` bug.

Answer (score 8):

```
for(i = 0;i<=3;i++){
//        ^^^^
```

You loop four times.

Over an array that has three elements.

Comment: @shekharsuman: Why is that?

Comment: Omg thank you so much didnt even notice that.I even did a step by step debug and didnt notice :(.

Comment: @shekharsuman: I go by the Stack Exchange model, not by Shekhar's made-up rules. This is the answer to the question, therefore I posted it as an answer. Answering questions in the comments section is _bad_ and _wrong_; unfortunately, it's a trend on the rise. It's a Q&A not a Q&C.

Comment: @jpw: There are over five minutes between my answer being posted and your comment being posted.

Comment: @shekharsuman one man's triviality is another man's significance. There are a *lot* of people reading this site who make mistakes in end conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an incorrect range of indices. As the original array has only 3 elements then the valid range of indices is `[0, 2]`. Thus in the loop within the function

```
for(i = 0; i<=3; i++) {
```

you are trying to access memory beyond the array when i is equal to 3.

But in any case the function design is not good. It uses magic number 3. So it can be applied only to arrays of three elements. Also you can not determine which element is the minimum and which element is the maximum.

The better approach is the following

```
typedef struct minmax 
{
    size_t min;
    size_t max;
} minmax_t;

minmax_t minmax_element( const int a[], size_t n ) 
{
    minmax_t result = { 0, 0 };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        if ( a[i] < a[result.min] )
        {
            result.min = i;
        }
        else if ( a[result.max] < a[i] ) 
        {
            result.max = i;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And in main the function can be called the following way

```
int main()
{
    int a[] = { 7, 8, 3 };
    minmax_t something;

    something  = minmax_element( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );

    printf( "Minimum is %d and max is %d\n", a[something.min], a[something.max] );

    int b[] = { 7, 8, 3, 0, 1, 5, 9 };

    something  = minmax_element( b, sizeof( b ) / sizeof( *b ) );

    printf( "Minimum is %d and max is %d\n", b[something.min], b[something.max] );
}
```

Take into account that in C++ there is corresponding algorithm `std::minmax_element` declared in header `<algorithm>` It returns a pair of pointers (iterators) of the first minimum element and the last maximum element. You can change the function that I have showed such a way that it will also return the index of the last maximum element in an array instead of the first maximum element.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof
```

To a proper resolution you should use the above to get the exact size of the array to use instead of i<=3.

Comment: You're wrong, when you declare function like ``void foo(int array[])`` it's almost the same as pass pointer ``void foo(int* array)``. Thus ``sizeof`` will return size of a pointer, not array. See on [ideone](http://ideone.com/birncE).