# c++ array undeclared identifier error

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm just pure C user.

I'm trying to implement with c++.
But I have hard understand point with array.

The code

**Question1**

```
...
float *input = read_file(arg[1], ..);
for(;)
{
  float *buf = input;
  buf[c] = 1;
}

for(;)
{
  buf[c] = 1;
}
```

As you can see above code, there are not exist buf declare.
But There are error like this 'buf' undeclared identifier.
I don't understand why this get error?
Should I have to declare identifier every time?

**Question2**

```
...
float *input = read_file(arg[1], ..);
for(;)
{
  float *buf = input;
  buf[c] = 2;
}

for(;)
{
  float *buf = input;
  buf[c] = 1;
}
```

If I modify the first buf array value, then the modified array value                  affect to second buf array. I don't understand. I have a new declare buf at second for sentence but still the modified value are affect to sencond buf array.

Comment: `float *but`, not `buf`, typo?

Comment: Thanks for letting me Yu Hao. It's typo

Comment: The code you posted isn't very clear, but you're only declaring `buf` within the scope of the `for` loop, which is why you wouldn't be able to access it in the second loop.

Comment: Arrays (not including VLAs) are so close in C vs. C++. I don't see why it has to do with using C++ instead of C.

Comment: @Alejandro Did you mean that declare which is like that way have only scope below?

Comment: @chris I'm trying to analysis from somebody code.

Comment: @jamji Try moving `float* buf = input;` right above the for loop , tell us what happens

Comment: @Alejandro I get it what you are saying. Thanks Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand how scopes work in C/C++. A variable declared in a scope is visible only inside that scope and inner scopes. In your case, you declare `buf` inside the local scope of the first `for` loop. It is not visible in the other `for` scope, as the scopes are distinct. As mentioned in the comments, you need to make the variable visible to both `for` scopes. The only solution: declare it in the outer scope of the `for` loops.

**EDIT**

You asked why can you modify the `input` via a variable visible in the local scope.  Well, your variable is a pointer `float* buf` that points to `input`. The latter is declared outside the scope, so it is visible by both `for` loops (their scope is enclosed, so they see the "outside world"). So, you can access it via your local pointer, and modify it accordingly.

The rule of thumb: from your house you can see the world, but the world cannot see inside your house (at least, if you're careful, and C/C++ compilers are quite careful).

Comment: Nicely stated, clear and concise.  You beat me to it!

Comment: @Alejandro not my intention to beat you to it :) I just think we should write an answer instead of comments (even for simple answers), as lately it become quite a trend to respond via short comments.

Comment: I sure have been noticing that lately I'm just afraid to be attacked for posting "comment"-like answers! =)

Comment: @Alejandro You should just ignore the attacks then. SO is not a Question & Comment site, it is a Question & Answer. Same "attack" happened here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30085517/3093378

Comment: Thnaks Sir. but there are still do not explained question2. As you can see, I have modified the buf array at first sentence then I can see the already modified data at second 'for state sentence'. Even there are not any global array. How can those buf share the modified data out of the scope?

Comment: @jamji see the updated edit. Local scopes can see (and modify) the data belonging to outside scopes, the reverse is not true.

Comment: @vsoftco Great house/world analogy